# C# Linq query to find invalid entries

Tags: c#, linq, validation

I'm trying do some manual validation for data in a List.

I have a MachineryRecord class which I sort then group by the JobNumber, now I need to find any results in each of the grouped lists that have overlapping times eg. Start time to End time overlaps another records StartTime to EndTime.

So far this is what I have got:

```
int invalidCount = 0;
var sorted = _machineRecords.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).ToList();
var grouped = sorted.GroupBy(x => x.JobNumber).ToList();
foreach(IGrouping<int,MachineryRecord> mac in grouped)     
{
   var queryResults = mac.//Linq query to find overlapping times
   invalidCount += queryResults.Count;
}
if(invalidCount > 0)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

and heres a cutdown version of MachineRecord object:

```
public class MachineryRecord
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public float StartTime { get; set; }
    public float EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is what is the linq query to achieve this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the format of time? why are you using float? is it 24hr based? can you show samples of start and end times?

Comment: sorry forgot to say StartTime and EndTime are taken from a counter in the machines similar to a odometer in a car but counting hours used. Hence using float for the times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two intervals `a` and `b` overlap if `a.StartTime < b.EndTime` and `a.EndTime > b.StartTime` assuming the start time is always before the end time. Therefore this can be expressed as follows.

```
var invalidCount = _machineRecords.Count(a =>
                       _machineRecords.Any(b =>
                           (a.ID != b.ID) &&
                           (a.JobNumber == b.JobNumber) &&
                           (a.StartTime < b.EndTime) &&
                           (a.EndTime > b.StartTime)));
```

Including the final check of `invalidCount` this can be simplified to a single return statement.

```
return !_machineRecords.Any(a =>
           _machineRecords.Any(b =>
               (a.ID != b.ID) &&
               (a.JobNumber == b.JobNumber) &&
               (a.StartTime < b.EndTime) &&
               (a.EndTime > b.StartTime)));
```

Comment: This has a small error where when checking the same MachineRecord it returns true. How would I modify this to fix that?

Comment: Already fix that - just compare the IDs or the references `a != b`.

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't take advantage of the fact the collection is sorted (by start date I'd assume?)

Comment: I don't think the records are sorted (by start time) because there is an explicit `OrderBy` in the question. It is not that trivial to optimize the method - if there are many violations it may slow down the whole thing if you sort it first because you would hit a violation early anyway. If violations are rare it would probably help to presort the data. Also grouping the data by job number as done in the question seems a good idea. But I decided to go for a relatively simple solution - if there are performance problems it is quite easy to tweak knowing the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-LINQ version that would use the fact the collection is sorted by start date:

```
    List<Tuple<MachineryRecord,MachineryRecord>> OverlapingRecords(IEnumerable<MachineryRecord> sortedRecords)
    {
        var result = new List<Tuple<MachineryRecord, MachineryRecord>>();
        MachineryRecord prev = null;
        foreach (var current in sortedRecords)
        {
            if (prev != null)
            {
                if (current.StartTime < prev.EndTime) { result.Add(new Tuple<MachineryRecord, MachineryRecord>(prev,current)); }
            }
            prev = current;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I haven't tested it though ;)